# React Router not passing params through useParams onto my page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a web page that I want to be dynamically routed with the `react-router-dom`, and `useParams()` does not hold the passed-in value on the final page that the route ends on.

Here are my routes:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { 
  BrowserRouter, 
  Routes, 
  Route, 
  } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import Items from "./routes/items";
import TextContentPage from "./routes/textContentPage";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import HomePage from "./routes/homePage";
import TopicPage from "./routes/topicPage";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CssBaseline />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="trees" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="items" element={<Items />} />
        <Route path="text-content" element={<TextContentPage />} />
        <Route path ="topics/:id" element={<TopicPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And here is the page I am trying to render:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
const topics = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Environement",
        fund: 0 
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Education",
        fund: 0 
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "International affairs",
        fund: 0 
    }
]

export default function TopicPage(){
    
    const topicId = useParams()
    let topic = topics.find(topic => topic.id === topicId)
    return (
        <Container maxWidth = "sm">
            <Header title = "Map The Future"> 
            </Header>
            <main>
                <Card><h2>{topic.name}</h2></Card>
            </main>
        </Container>
        
    );

}
```

Any Help figuring out how to get `useParams()` to work would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You've a typo, the route match params are key-value pairs on a returned params object, i.e. `const { id } = useParams()` instead of `const id = useParams()`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**`useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters.**

And since you've define path as:
`<Route path ="topics/:id" element={<TopicPage />} />`
While accessing `useParams` since it returns an object you'll get key/value pair so use object destructuring `const {id} = useParams()` and since it's of type `String` you need to `parseInt` the returned value.

```
export default function TopicPage(){
    
    const {id} = useParams()
    let topic = topics.find(topic => topic.id === parseInt(id)) // Change here
    return (
        <Container maxWidth = "sm">
            <Header title = "Map The Future"> 
            </Header>
            <main>
                <Card><h2>{topic.name}</h2></Card>
            </main>
        </Container>
        
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spotted two issues with your code. Try these edits and see if they help.

1. `useParams` returns object, so try using the object destructuring syntax:

`let { id } = useParams()`

Your variable name needs to match what you used in your `<Route />` component - "id".

2. Since the `useParams` values are grabbed from the URL, they're `String` types.
   To convert to integers:

`id = parseInt(id, 10)`